# Android Shared Preferences using getter/setter methods fail to display

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, getter-setter, findall

My Android app fails to display the shared preferences that I set in a different class. 
Am I missing something in my code? I save them fine but they don't display in my main Activity. All I see is the default text when I run the app. I have tried all I can to no avail. I can't figure out where the problem is. Below are my code files:

**1. MnsEditor.java**

```
    public class MnsEditor extends Activity {

    private MsItem mnses;
    private Button saveBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mns_editor);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        mnses = new MsItem();
        mnses.setStartKey(intent.getStringExtra("startKey"));
        mnses.setStartDate(intent.getStringExtra("StartDate"));

        mnses.setShiftKey(intent.getStringExtra("ShiftKey"));
        mnses.setShift(intent.getStringExtra("Shift"));


        mnses.setBKey(intent.getStringExtra("BKey"));
        mnses.setB(intent.getStringExtra("B"));

        mnses.setGKey(intent.getStringExtra("GKey"));
        mnses.setG(intent.getStringExtra("G"));

        mnses.setNxtKey(intent.getStringExtra("NxtKey"));
        mnses.setNxt(intent.getStringExtra("Nxt"));


        EditText ms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sdate);
        ms.setText(mnses.getStartDate());

        EditText sh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sDay);
        sh.setText(mnses.getShift());

        EditText bb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bB);
        bb.setText(mnses.getB());

        EditText bg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bG);
        bg.setText(mnses.getG());

        EditText nm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Nxt);
        nm.setText(mnses.getNxt());

        saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savePrefs);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveAndFinish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveAndFinish() {
        EditText mst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stDay);
        String mnsesStart = mst.getText().toString();

        EditText shi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ShiftDay);
        String shift = shi.getText().toString();

        EditText bb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bbB);
        String bbb = b.getText().toString();

        EditText gg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ggG);
        String ggg = gg.getText().toString();

        EditText nxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Nxt);
        String next = nxt.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("startdatekey", mnses.getStartDate());
        intent.putExtra("StartDate", mnsesStart);
        intent.putExtra("ShiftKey", mnses.getShift());
        intent.putExtra("Shift", shift);
        intent.putExtra("BKey", mnses.getB());
        intent.putExtra("B", bbb);
        intent.putExtra("GKey", mnses.getG());
        intent.putExtra("G", ggg);
        intent.putExtra("NxtKey", mnses.getNxt());
        intent.putExtra("Nxt", next);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();

    }

}
```

**2. MsDataSource.java**

```
   public class MsDataSource {

        MsItem mnses;


private static final String MNS_PREFS = "mnsKEY";
public SharedPreferences mnsPrefs;

public static final String StartDate = "startKey";
public static final String Shift = "shiftKey";
public static final String B = "bKey";
public static final String G = "gKey";
public static final String Nxt = "nxtKey";  

public MsDataSource(Context context) {
    mnsPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MNS_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

    public String getTheStartDate() {
        String mnsstart = mensPrefs.getString(StartDate, "Not seen");
        return mnsstart;                    
    }
    public String getTheShift() {
        String shiftda = mensPrefs.getString(Ovulation, "no data");
        return shiftda;                 
    }
    public String getTheBoy() {
        String Bda = mensPrefs.getString(B, "not accessible");
        return Bda;                 
    }
    public String getTheGirl() {
        String Gda = mensPrefs.getString(G, "does not exist");
        return Gda;                 
    }
    public String getTheNextMenses() {
        String nxtmns = mensPrefs.getString(Nxt, "maybe later");
        return nxtmns;                  
    }

            public boolean update(mnsesItem mns) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mnsPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString(mns.getStartKey(), mns.getStartDate());
                editor.putString(mns.getShiftKey(), mns.getShift());
                editor.putString(mns.getBKey(), mns.getB());
                editor.putString(mns.getGKey(), mns.getG());
                editor.putString(mns.getNxtKey(), mns.getNxt());
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            }

    }
```

**3. Mst.java**

```
public class Mst extends Activity {

    private TextView startdate;
    private TextView shiftday;
    private TextView bday;
    private TextView gday;
    private TextView nextday;

    public static final String StartDate = "startKey";
    public static final String Shift = "shiftKey";
    public static final String B = "bKey";
    public static final String G = "gKey";
    public static final String Nxt = "nxtKey";

    private static final int EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST = 1001;
    private MsDataSource datasource;
    MsItem mnses;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mns_layout);

        startdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mnsstartd);
        shiftday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shd);
        bday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bbd);
        gday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bgd);
        nextday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nxtmnsd);

        datasource = new MsDataSource(this);

        refreshDisplay();   
    }

    private void refreshDisplay() {
        mnses = datasource.findAll();
        startdate.setText(datasource.mnsPrefs.getString(StartDate, "not retrieved"));
        shiftday.setText(datasource.mnsPrefs.getString(Shift, "unavailable"));
        bday.setText(datasource.mnsPrefs.getString(B, "not seen"));
        gday.setText(datasource.mnsPrefs.getString(G, "not found"));
        nextday.setText(datasource.mnsPrefs.getString(Nxt, "no data"));     

    }

    private void createMns() {
        MsItem mns = MsItem.getNew();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MnsEditor.class);
        intent.putExtra("startKey", mns.getStartKey());
        intent.putExtra("StartDate", mns.getStartDate());
        intent.putExtra("shiftKey", mns.getShiftKey());
        intent.putExtra("Shift", mns.getShift());
        intent.putExtra("bKey", mns.getBKey());
        intent.putExtra("B", mns.getB());
        intent.putExtra("gKey", mns.getGKey());
        intent.putExtra("G", mns.getG());
        intent.putExtra("nxtKey", mns.getNxtKey());
        intent.putExtra("Nxt", mns.getNxt());

        startActivityForResult(intent, EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == EDITOR_ACTIVITY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            MsItem mns = new MsItem();
            mns.setStartKey(data.getStringExtra("startKey"));
            mns.setStartDate(data.getStringExtra("StartDate"));
            mns.setShiftKey(data.getStringExtra("shiftKey"));
            mns.setShift(data.getStringExtra("Shift"));
            mns.setBKey(data.getStringExtra("bKey"));
            mns.setB(data.getStringExtra("B"));
            mns.setGKey(data.getStringExtra("gKey"));
            mns.setG(data.getStringExtra("G"));
            mns.setNextmnsesKey(data.getStringExtra("nxtKey"));
            mns.setNxt(data.getStringExtra("Nxt"));

            datasource.update(mns);

            refreshDisplay();
        }
    }

}
```

**4. MsItem.java**

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class MsItem {

    private String startKey;
    private String StartDate;

    private String shiftKey;
    private String Shift;

    private String bKey;
    private String B;

    private String gKey;
    private String G;

    private String nxtKey;
    private String Nxt;


    public String getStartKey() {
        return startKey;
    }
    public void setStartKey(String startKey) {
        this.startKey = startKey;
    }
    public String getStartDate() {
        return StartDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        StartDate = startDate;
    }
    public String getShiftKey() {
        return shiftKey;
    }
    public void setShiftKey(String shiftKey) {
        this.shiftKey = shiftKey;
    }
    public String getShift() {
        return Shift;
    }
    public void setShift(String shift) {
        Shift = shift;
    }
    public String getbKey() {
        return bKey;
    }
    public void setbKey(String bKey) {
        this.bKey = bKey;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return B;
    }
    public void setB(String b) {
        B = b;
    }
    public String getgKey() {
        return gKey;
    }
    public void setgKey(String gKey) {
        this.gKey = gKey;
    }
    public String getG() {
        return G;
    }
    public void setG(String g) {
        G = g;
    }
    public String getNxtKey() {
        return nxtKey;
    }
    public void setNxtKey(String nxtKey) {
        this.nxtKey = nxtKey;
    }
    public String getNxt() {
        return Nxt;
    }
    public void setNxt(String nxt) {
        Nxt = nxt;
    }


    public static MsItem getNew(){

        Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        String startdatekey = formatter.format(new Date());

        String skey = formatter.format(new Date());

        String bkey = formatter.format(new Date());

        String gkey = formatter.format(new Date());

        String nkey = formatter.format(new Date());

        MsItem mnses = new MsItem();
        mnses.setStartKey(startdatekey);
        mnses.setStartDate("");

        mnses.setShiftKey(skey);
        mnses.setShift("");

        mnses.setbKey(bkey);
        mnses.setB("");

        mnses.setgKey(gkey);
        mnses.setG("");

        mnses.setNxtKey(nkey);
        mnses.setNxt("");
        return mnses;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try this: mnsPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(StartDate, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  String mnsstart = mnsPrefs.getString(StartDate, "");

Comment: @bean_droid, Do you mean, I put those pieces together in the `findAll()` method? Coz I already have them exactly the way you have put them here but only that they are in different sections of the code.

Comment: @Der Golem, I have updated the code with the `update()` class in the **2. MsDataSource.java** file that does the commits.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can see is, that You are trying to get the sharedPreferences, but You are initializing the same object a few times inside Your MsDataSource.java class:

```
    mnsPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(StartDate, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mnsPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(shift, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mnsPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(B, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mnsPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(G, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mnsPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Nxt, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

So this will not work. For different sharedPref objects, You need to initialize them unique for example:

```
      public SharedPreferences mnsPrefs1;
      public SharedPreferences mnsPrefs2;
      public SharedPreferences mnsPrefs3;
      public SharedPreferences mnsPrefs4;
      public SharedPreferences mnsPrefs5;


    mnsPrefs1 = context.getSharedPreferences(StartDate, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mnsPrefs2 = context.getSharedPreferences(shift, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mnsPrefs3 = context.getSharedPreferences(B, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mnsPrefs4 = context.getSharedPreferences(G, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mnsPrefs5 = context.getSharedPreferences(Nxt, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

but there must be more. I need to see Your code from MsItem.java class, I think, here You are saving the SharedPrefs, right?

### EDIT

You don´t need to initialize so many SharedPreference objects, it´s enough to make only one and give it different keys for every value. For example:

private final String sharedPrefKey = "MY_KEY";

```
   public MsDataSource(Context context) {
    mnsPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   }
```

and then update() method in MsDataSource.java should work. But by the way, I think Your initialization of Your MsItem in Your Mst.java class at onActivityResult is made in the wrong way, isn´t it? You wrote

```
   MsItem mns = new MsItem();
```

But musn´t it be

```
   MsItem mns = MsItem.getNew();
```

? Because with only new MsItem(), all the Strings and stuff are not initialized inside MsItem.

Comment: Let me try your suggestion. Please check the updated code files; I have added  **4. MsItem.java** as you said. Yeah, I am saving the data and trying to retrieve it at the same time.

Comment: Yep, I see now, that´s like I said, You save this values with one SharedPreferences Object initialized a few times. So, just make this like I written above and give it a try. Init every Preference unique. But by the way, why You are doing this? I think You don´t need so much objects, You can use only one SharedPreferences object and give it different keys.

Comment: can You update the post to your current code please: I think there are more issues. On was the sharedPrefs, let´s see what´s next...

Comment: I have updated the code to its current state, please check it out.

Comment: The initialization of **MsItem** in `Mst.java` is fine coz the `getNew()` method is already called in the `createMns()` method of the same class.

Comment: ok, another question, I can´t see Your datasource.findAll(); method. Is this not posted or am I just blind? Can You please post this method?

Comment: I replaced it with the individual methods you see there like:  `public String getTheStartDate() {
        String mnsstart = mensPrefs.getString(StartDate, "Not seen");
        return mnsstart;                    
    }`, etc.  


Thanks for your tireless help. To save my time, I have resorted to using SQLite to accomplish what I wanted to do. You may still continue to find a solution for this to help another person in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String getStartDate(){
       mnsPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(StartDate, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      String mnsstart = mnsPrefs.getString(StartDate, "");
      return mnsstart;
}

 public String getShift(){
       mnsPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(shift, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      String shiftda = mnsPrefs.getString(Shift, "");
      return shiftda;
}
```

its more readable

Comment: I tried out this but still nothing displays, any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use MODE_APPEND instead MODE_PRIVATE.

MODE_APPEND(File creation mode: for use with openFileOutput, if the file already exists then write data to the end of the existing file instead of erasing it).

```
  SharedPreferences editor = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "used_name", Context.MODE_APPEND);

  editor.putString("username", value);
  editor.commit();
```

Comment: at Applexus Technc, In fact I need these preferences to exist only once and if they exist, be overwritten.

Comment: With the "username" key, it 'll be overwritten.